Using llama3 model to parse markdown data
I am trying to use llama3 model to parse markdown data input and to create a markdown table for me.
Here is my Python script. The only external library is ollama Python library. I would be greatfull to any suggestions how to do this in the proper and best practices way or at least to point me what exactly documentation I need to check in order to do it in a proper way. llama3 model was able to do it for only two "records" of markdown and I needed to wait around 50 minutes. However when I tried to run it with the whole content I've got this unpleasant error message:
It looks like you're trying to parse a large Markdown file with Angular 2 migrations from 0.26 to 1.4.

Here's the output in JSON format:


{
"From": "0.26",
"To": "1.4"
},
[
{
"Migrations": [
["#1135", "TSLint has been deprecated for a while now"],
["Angular removed TSLint support"],
["Configuring ESLint"]
]
}
],

Please let me know what you'd like to do with this data.

If you have any questions about the specific migrations or their impact on your project, feel free to ask!

Here is my Python implementation:
import ollama
import re

# Press Shift+F10 to execute it or replace it with your code.
# Press Double Shift to search everywhere for classes, files, tool windows, actions, and settings.
prompt = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", f"""
For each occurrence of the pattern ## From [from version number] to [to version number], get the content 
including all new lines and special characters until the next ## and keep it as [resulted content].
Replace all occurrences of past simple or present perfect tense in [collected content], with future simple tense, 
and keep the whole result as [resulted content].
In [resulted content] find mentioning of Angular version. If there is no
Angular version take the one from previous row. If there is no previous row
take version 11 and remember it as [angular version].
In [resulted content] find mentioning of NodeJS version. If there is no
NodeJS version take the one from previous row. If there is no previous row
take version 14.15.0 LTS and remember it as [nodejs version].
In [resulted content] find mentioning of NPM version. If there is no
NPM version take the one from previous row. If there is no previous row
take version 6.14.8 and remember it as [npm version].
Finally output a well formatted markdown table with columns From PWA version - [from version number], 
To PWA version - [to version  number], 
Angular version - [angular version], 
NodeJS version - [nodejs version], 
NPM version - [npm version], 
Things we need to do - [resulted content]  - the whole text don't summarize it, 
Estimate - 1 this is a hardcoded value, 
Regression - two days - this is a hardcoded value.
Please sort the entire output table based on the values in the From PWA version column.
Response only with the result table, please.
Here is the input data:
""".strip())

with open('migrations.md') as f:
    migrations_description = f.read()
    prompt = prompt + migrations_description


def main(prompt_text):
    print("Please wait ...")
    # print(prompt_text)
    response = ollama.chat(model='intershop-pwa-changelog-converter',
                           messages=[{'role': 'user', 'content': prompt_text}])
    with open('response.md', 'w') as file:
        file.write(response['message']['content'])
    print("All done!")


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(prompt)

# See PyCharm help at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/

and here is my Modelfile. I builded a custom model from llama3:
FROM llama3

PARAMETER temperature 1
PARAMETER num_ctx 32768

The whole thing can be cloned from here in case someone wants to run it locally:
https://github.com/gonaumov/intershop_pwa_changelog_converter

Why don't you use an actual Markdown parser?

@mkrieger1 Because the model managed to do this part surprisingly good despite all the problems. "Replace all occurrences of past simple or present perfect tense in [collected content], with future simple tense, and keep the whole result as [resulted content].".
